# How to change multiple image at once in gridview in Android?

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter

I'm working on AndroidStudio with Java.

I have many imageviews inside gridview.
and I'm trying to apply click event which affects multiple imageviews at the same time

what I want to do is :
when one imageview is clicked another imageview, which is not been clicked to change its image.

for example, there is two imageview A and B in same gridview. if I click A imageview, both A and B imageview set to different imagesources.

what I can do is change only clicked imageview.
I want to know how to access the unclicked items in gridview.
I made onclick listener inside adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.ingrid,parent,false);

            ImageView blackorwhite = convertView.findViewById(R.id.blackOrWhite);

            Integer val = mData.get(position);
            blackorwhite.setImageResource(blockColor.get(val));
            blackorwhite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    blackorwhite.setImageResource(R.color.white);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make an interface callback to know which item gets clicked for example this is ur interface

```
interface OnClickListener {
    void onClick(int position)
}
```

and pass this interface to ur Adapter,
and in the getView method whenever a view get clicked u can call the onClick method of the interface

this is example code

```
interface OnClickListener {
    void onClick(int position);
}

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private List<String> list;
    private OnClickListener listener;

    private Context context;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context,List<String> list,OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       View  view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(ur layout);


       view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               listener.onClick(position);
           }
       });

        return view;
    }
}
```

To initiate The adapter, u can use this code,

```
 GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(context, imageList, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int position) {
                // this method called every time an view get clicked
                // and u can change the DataSet which now is imageList
               // imageList.set(position,"something new ");
                // after the change of DataSet u should cal the notifyDataSetChanged
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks its super helpful. I never know that  I can update my dataset(Imagelist)